# laravel - postman returns HTML instead of JSON?

Tags: laravel, api, postman

Trying to simulate a POST request on postman for a callback function for API. It is from an external API posting the data to me so I did not include return in callback function.

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('api-callback','APIController@callback')->name('api-callback');
```

Controller:

```
 public function callback(Request $request){
        Log::info('callback function is called');
        $response = request()->all();
        Log::info($response);

        if($request->status == 1){

        //store transaction details
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->user_id = auth()->id();
        $transaction->billcode = $request->billcode;
        $transaction->transaction_id = $request->refno;
        $transaction->amount = $request->amount;
        $transaction->save();

        //update new credit balance for user
        $user_credit = UserInfo::where('user_id',auth()->id());
        $user_credit->credit += $request->amount;
        $user_credit->save();

        }
```

The expected result is to return 1(success). I tested it few days ago and it works as expected but I tried it again today and it is returning me HTML text with no errors. The status is 200 as well. Screenshot just for reference.

How should I debug this?

Comment: As I see You don't have anything returned from your callback method.

Comment: You're not returning anything!!

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze This is from an external API returning response to me. I did not return anything in my callback method the other day and it works as well.

Comment: If you don't return anything from controller it will display nothing

Comment: @CookieMonster21 you are not returning anything in the code you shared. If some other code is causing things to be returned then also share that other code. Usually to get JSON back you have to send an `Accept: application/json` header with postman but it's also unclear if you are doing that

Answer (score 3):

By default, Laravel return html formatted response - for json - client must set Header Accept:application/json

I created middleware for solve this problem - because, in my opinion, api must return json in all cases, if you support only json schema.

app/Http/Middleware/ForceJsonResponse.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ForceJsonResponse
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

app/Http/Kernel.php

```
...
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //other middlewares
    'json' => \App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
];
...
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        //other middlewares
        'json'
    ],
];
...
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the settings in postman rather than laravel itself?  I just don't know why it works the other day and I didn't change anything at all.

Comment: You can set this header it postman in Headers tab.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are sending a form-data and have forgotten to add `Accept: Application/json` in your header. If you do that, laravel will automatically return all responses in `json`.

You can either send form-data with that header, or in postman use **raw body** with type **json** and the postman will add that header for you.

Also in your function, you have no return at the end, like:

```php
return response()->json([
    "status" => 200,
    "message" => "Success",
    "data" => $transaction
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
 public function callback(Request $request){
    Log::info('callback function is called');
    $response = request()->all();
    Log::info($response);

    if($request->status == 1){

    //store transaction details
    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->user_id = auth()->id();
    $transaction->billcode = $request->billcode;
    $transaction->transaction_id = $request->refno;
    $transaction->amount = $request->amount;
    $transaction->save();

    //update new credit balance for user
    $user_credit = UserInfo::where('user_id',auth()->id());
    $user_credit->credit += $request->amount;
    $user_credit->save();
     
    return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 201);
    }
```

Comment: but it couldn't retrieve my auth()->id()