# What is the proper way to set a default Exception rendering method in Laravel 10.x?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

According the the Laravel docs, there are multiple way to render Exceptions in the App\Exceptions\Handler class.

By default, Exceptions are rendered in HTML, which isn't great for APIs.
The default method, `render`, can be overridden like this:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    return response()->json([
        "error" => $e->getMessage()
    ], 500);
}
```

Specific Exception handling can also be managed in the `register` method like this:

```
public function register(): void
{
    $this->renderable(function (CustomExceptionA $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'details' => 'some custom stuff'
        ], 400);
    });

    $this->renderable(function (CustomExceptionB $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'details' => 'some other custom stuff'
        ], 404);
    });
}
```

Now, one would assume that the `render` method would take care of rendering exceptions **unless** the exception thrown has been defined as renderable in the `register` method. However, it appears that when the `render` method is overridden, everything defined as renderable in the `register` method are simply ignored. It's weird to me that both these approaches are mutually exclusive.

So what is the right way to set a default rendering method?

In the past, I've dealt with this by using only the `render` method, and having a huge if/else statement using `instanceof`, but that feels dirty.

I suppose the other option would be to completely forego the `render` method, and add `$this->renderable(function (Throwable $e) { ... });` at the bottom of the `register` method.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: If your question EXACTLY about json vs html - check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68408722/11251946

Comment: @Maksim Thanks but no, my question isn't really about json vs html. I don't want to rely on Laravel's default rendering, because even for generic exceptions, I need to add custom stuff (like a request ID generated by my app).

Comment: For request id - renderable() is good place. I think overwrite render method - bad practice (IMHO)